# logstash kafka input performance / config tuning

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, apache-kafka-connect

I use logstash to transfer data from Kafka to Elasticsearch and I'm getting the following error:

```
WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Auto offset commit failed for group kafka-es-sink: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

I tried to adjust the session timeout (to 30000) and max poll records (to 250).

The topic produces 1000 events per seconds in avro format. There are 10 partitions (2 servers) and two logstash instances with 5 consumer threads each.

I have no problems with other topics with ~100-300 events per second.

I think it should be a config issue because I also have a second connector between Kafka and Elasticsearch on the same topic which works fine (confluent's kafka-connect-elasticsearch)

The main aim is to compare kafka connect and logstash as connector. Maybe anyone has also some experience in general?